# How can I provide to terraform different aws credentials to s3 backend and ec2 with role_arn usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to store terraform state files in s3 bucket in one aws account and deploy instance changes in another aws account with role_arn usage.
This is my configuration:
**providers.tf**

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "bucket"
    key = "tf/terraform.tfstate"
    encrypt = "false"
    region = "us-east-1"
    profile = "s3"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:role/s3-role"
    dynamodb_table = "name"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "ec2"
  region = "eu-north-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::2222222222222:role/ec2-role"
  }
}
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[s3-def]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = sssssssss
[ec2-def]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = sssss
[s3]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/s3-role
region = us-east-1
source_profile = s3-def
[ec2]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/ec2-role
region = eu-north-1
source_profile = ec2-def
```

And when I try terraform init -migrate-state I get:

```
2022-08-03T17:23:21.334+0300 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.2.5
2022-08-03T17:23:21.334+0300 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.18.1
2022-08-03T17:23:21.334+0300 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"terraform", "init", "-migrate-state"}
2022-08-03T17:23:21.334+0300 [INFO]  Loading CLI configuration from /
2022-08-03T17:23:21.335+0300 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"init", "-migrate-state"}

Initializing the backend...
2022-08-03T17:23:21.337+0300 [WARN]  backend config has changed since last init
Backend configuration changed!

Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.

2022-08-03T17:23:21.338+0300 [INFO]  Attempting to use session-derived credentials
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
│ 
│ Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
```

I just dont understand what is this error and it even possible to provide two different set of credentials to s3 and ec2?

Comment: Do you have any `AWS_*` environment variables set? Also, rather than using `source_profile` could you try to explicitly set the secret and access key to the `s3` and `ec2` profiles?

Comment: Nope, I drop all env variables with command `unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`  
And I also already tried explicity set keys, this configuration also leads to same error.

Comment: @Ranburu did you solve your issue?

Comment: @DiegoSierraFernandez Nope, I just dropped the idea, looks like there no way to do that. For now I use one account but with different roles

Comment: Yep, the only way is to have one user with permissions to assume roles in other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you can't authenticate to manage your remote state.  Don't try to handle resources in another account until you get your basic `terraform init` working.

Once you have that working, use provider aliasing to access multiple accounts.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations